# How to schedule a report with collection type parameter via REST API in JasperReports Server?

Tags: rest, jasperserver

I'm using *JasperReports Server v4.5*.

We are having difficulties with scheduling a report by using *REST API*.

We are able to schedule a report that only accepts string parameters however the problem begins with a report that has a *java.util.Collection* type parameter. We tried everything but couldn't find the correct type for *java.util.Collection*.

Right now this works:

```xml
<parameters>
    <name>string_input</name>
    <value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        test
    </value>
</parameters>
```

But we couldn't get this working:

```xml
<parameters>
    <name>array_parameter</name>
    <value type=? >[1, 2, 3]</value>
</parameters>
```

When I looked into the code, I can see that *JasperReports Server* WS accepts arrays, however there is no documented way to send the arrays or array types.

What is the correct way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```xml
<parameters>
    <entry>
        <key>param_name</key>
        <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="collection">
            <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">1</item>
            <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">2</item>
        </value>
    </entry>
</parameters>
```

**Update:**

Some have suggested removing the `entry` tags. If the above does not work, try removing the `entry` tags.